# I can not understand with the fragments and BackStack

Tags: android

I have aсivity with one button and frame:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="new fragment"
            android:id="@+id/replaceFragment" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/contentFrame">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button replaceBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.replaceFragment);
        replaceBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.replaceFragment:
                Fragment fragment1 = new Frag1();
                FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fTrans.replace(R.id.contentFrame, fragment1);
                fTrans.commit();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

button is pressed, etc. I create a fragment:

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment  implements View.OnClickListener {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, null);
        Button replaceBtn2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.replaceFragment2);
        replaceBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.replaceFragment2:
                Frag2 fragment2 = new Frag2();
                FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fTrans.replace(R.id.contentFrame,fragment2);
                fTrans.commit();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

it also has a button which when pressed I create fragment2:

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2, null);
        Button replaceBtn3 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.replaceFragment3);
        replaceBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.replaceFragment3:
                Frag3 fragment3 = new Frag3();
                FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fTrans.replace(R.id.contentFrame,fragment3);
                fTrans.commit();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

fragment2 also creates a new fragment3:

```
public class Frag3 extends Fragment{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag3, null);
        return v;
    }
}
```

if I do when creating each fragment will add a line:

```
fTrans.addToBackStack(null);
```

then later when I press the "back" button on the screen will appear the fragments in reverse order. but I want to when I'm in fragmente3 when you press the "back" appears immediately fragment1.
if I do not add the line `fTrans.addToBackStack(null);` in fragment2 they overlap.

Comment: but, what is your question? about how it works? what to do? info?

Comment: how to do so by clicking on fragment3 and pressing the "back" I got on fragment1. I did it but fragment1 superimposed on fragment3

Answer (score 0):

in order to do that, you can keep the **`fragments backStack`** references in your **`activity`** or for example **`onBackPressed`** you could try something like below:

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
        //back to fragment 1.
    }
```

Comment: did not quite understand. I need to remove a fragment of which I am, after pressing the "back"-because it stays in the frame

Comment: i didn't get what you mentioned ? but if what i think of, if your fragment overlap the other fragment view, then dont use frameLayout just use linearLayout

Comment: tried. the same thing. the bottom line is that fragment3 remains on the frame and the top of it appears fragment1. ie I need to somehow remove the (cleaned) the last fragment of which I am after clicking on the back button

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a function which I use for one of my projects. I implemented it in the parent of the Activity that manages the fragments. I don't know if I'm going to clarify anything about the behaviour because all you tell us in you question make sense to me.

I my case, it was a simple app (almost static), but it changes fragments and, as you want to, many times I want to go back two fragment in "history" so I think it could help.

```
@Override
   public void replaceFragment(FRAGMENT_TYPE destinyFragmentType, int fragmentContainerID, boolean addToBackStack) {
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      Fragment currentFragment = FragmentFactory.getFragment(destinyFragmentType);
      fragmentTransaction.replace(fragmentContainerID, currentFragment);

      if (addToBackStack) {
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
      }

      fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Notes:

- The second parameter is the parameter that indicates if you want to
  keep in history or not. For your case: frg1 -> fr2 : param true; fr2
  -> fr3 : param false;
- I used a Factory in order to get a cleaner code, but you can use
  whatever you want, change the header, give the function your fragment
  etc.

I hope this helps!!

Comment: fragments that I do not need so do not put in BackStack. the problem with the last fragment. it is applied to a fragment of which was last in BackStack.